# Salt: What does [] mean?

Tags: salt-stack

What does `[]` mean in Salt here?

```
httpd:
  pkg.installed: []
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    - source: salt://httpd/httpd.conf
    - require:
      - pkg: httpd
```

From https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/ordering.html#requisite-statements

I have enough fantasy to guess the meaning but ... is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

This is just an example of un-coordinate salt developer bad documentation habits, that assume you know the too-flexible salt state tree structure.

You need to understand there is a lots of shortcut in saltstack. Take the example posted.

```
# you can write this "shorthand" to install httpd
# http are ID and also package name
httpd:
  pkg.installed

# this do similar works. I specify a more descriptive ID 
install-http-package: 
  pkg.installed:
    - name: http

# this install httpd package together with other package.  Again I use descriptive ID 
install-web-app-pacakges:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - httpd
      - php5
      - django
```

So the issues is about the first level "id". Saltstack will traverse the whole yaml tree to determine whether it is a descriptive value, or use it as a package name.

However, the parsing need to conform to some format so it doesn't failed. If you overdo the shorthand, the parser will get confuse. A shorthand only deal with 2 line of value.

So to overcome the problem, the empty list value [] is passed.  then parser see the [] and agree that it will pass the descriptive ID httpd as package name, and continue to rest of other action.

In fact the "shorthand group" can be write as this.

```
# Use simple shorthand 
httpd:
  pkg.installed

copy-customise-httpd.conf-to-server:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    - source: salt://httpd/httpd.conf
    - require:
      - pkg: httpd
```

There is no advantage to overdo shorthand. You just save a few line of typing.  shorthand is one of the cause of salt-stack yaml config steep learning curve.

And there is another catch of using the package name as id : ID must be unique. You may ramp into some error if you reuse them because of some trivia reason.

Comment: I hope salt fails and does nothing if you have duplicate IDs.

Comment: Don't worry, salt will warn you and stop.

Answer (score 1):

It's just shorthand for nothing. Yaml requires it so you can have the `file.managed` right below it. You could also format it like this:

```
httpd:
  pkg:
    - installed
  file:
    - managed:
    - name: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    - source: salt://httpd/httpd.conf
    - require:
      - pkg: httpd
```